# Rolling 12 Months Decrements in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, rollup

I have data something like this

```
YearMonth   Recovery   Segment
 201701      0.002       NULL
   .           .          .
   .           .          .
 201712      0.002       NULL
 201801      0.002       NULL
   .           .          .
   .           .          .
 201812      0.002       NULL
```

Likewise, I have data for 10 years, I want to populate Segment Column using Recovery column (distinct throughout 10 years). For first-year 201701-201712, Segment is 0.002 then for next year 201801-201812 it is 0.002*(1 - 0.2) = 0.0004 after that for 201901-201912 it is 0.0004*(1-0.2) and so on.

I was trying it with join logic but couldn't able to move forward after one year. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The new data would look like this

```
YearMonth   Recovery   Segment
 201701      0.002       0.002
   .           .          .
   .           .          .
 201712      0.002       0.002
 201801      0.002       0.0004
   .           .          .
   .           .          .
 201812      0.002       0.0004
```

Comment: How come 0.002*(1-0.2) = 0.0004? Did you mean multiply by 0.2 each year? 0.002*0.2 = 0.0004, no?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a calculation error it should be 0.0016. Actually, I want an annual reduction of 20% in Recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this as a problem in arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       recovery * power(1 - 0.2, convert(int, left(yearmonth, 4)) - 2017) as segment
from t;
```

The `0.2` is for a 20% reduction.

If you actually want to set the value:

```
update t
    set segment = recovery * power(1 - 0.2, convert(int, left(yearmonth, 4)) - 2017);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE
(
    YearMonth INT,
    Recovery DECIMAL(20, 10),
    Segment DECIMAL(20, 10)
);

WITH months
AS (SELECT TOP (10 * 12)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) AS MonthNo
    FROM sys.all_columns t1
        INNER JOIN sys.all_columns t2
            ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id),
     dates (d)
AS (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, MonthNo - 1, '20170101')
    FROM months)
INSERT INTO @Source
(
    YearMonth,
    [Recovery]
)
SELECT YEAR(d) * 100 + MONTH(d),
       0.002
FROM dates;


UPDATE @Source
SET Segment = [Recovery] * POWER(1 - 0.20000, YearMonth / 100 - 2017);

SELECT *
FROM @Source;
```